# Safety with low voltage high current safety

Tags: power-supply, safety, high-current, low-voltage

For my work, I’m working on a project that uses a power supply that outputs 42A DC at 5V limit.

While I know that 5V is nothing if I were to come into contact, poor grounding can still cause flashes and burns.

So what are good safety tips when dealing with this sort of supply? Thanks!

Comment: Always use wire with sufficient ampacity rating. Test all solder joints, or other connections for low resistance. If possible, avoid disconnecting wires with the power on, as there may be a significant "inductive kick".

Comment: Avoid under-rated contacts.

Comment: Avoid wearing metal rings or jewelry.  Getting a ring across a 42A supply can get uncomfortable fast.

Answer (score 1):

5V, as said, is safe by all means (less than 60V, by IEC, CENELEC ad UL standards, ad less than 50 V, OSHA).

John D mentioned correctly the problem of burns, if you wear a metal ring.

Then you have to consider the way you interrupt the 42A and if there is a connector that should bring that current and may be extracted with current on. Usually I put several contacts in parallel. With 5V however arcing should be every limited. If I have to switch off 42A dc I would use relays with contacts in parallel: I have a heap of Omron G2RL and they perform quite well.

Answer (score 0):

IEC and UL norms states that you can touch with your finger, without health risks, the following 2 types of voltages with respect to the ground of the circuit AND with respect to EARTH:

DC voltages: max 60 VDC

Non DC voltages: max 42 Vpp (peak to peak)

Those are considered safe voltages that we all human beings can safely touch.

---

If your power supply is UL6950 or UL62368 compliant than you are safe even without plastic sole shoes.